# Get multiple max values sorting date time

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, datefield

Here is my sample data.
DateAndTime column measured per 10 seconds.
Date range is 6/30 ~ 8/31.
[DateAndTime], [TagName] is varchar(50).

```
DateAndTime             TagName        DataValue
2022-06-30 14:15:40    BW004_GD-4-16   99
2022-06-30 14:15:50    BW004_GD-4-16   25
2022-06-30 14:16:00    BW004_GD-4-16   99
2022-06-30 14:16:10    BW004_GD-4-16   50
2022-06-30 14:16:20    BW004_GD-4-16   99
2022-06-30 14:16:30    BW004_GD-4-16   99
.
.
.
2022-06-30 14:15:40    BW004_GD-4-17   50
2022-06-30 14:15:50    BW004_GD-4-17   40
2022-06-30 14:16:00    BW004_GD-4-17   25
.
.
.
2022-06-30 18:20:00    BW004_GD-4-17   50
2022-06-30 18:20:10    BW004_GD-4-17   50
2022-06-30 18:20:20    BW004_GD-4-17   10
.
.
.
2022-06-30 14:15:40    BW004_GD-4-18   30
2022-06-30 14:15:50    BW004_GD-4-18   40  
2022-06-30 14:16:00    BW004_GD-4-18   100
.
.
.
```

Here is problem.

1. DateAndtime is CharField, not date field.
2. maximum datavalue is duplicated.

I want to extract the maximum and earliest datetime of each tag by day of the week sorted by DateAndTime.

Result example:

```
DateAndTime            TagName         MaxValue  
2022-06-30 14:15:40    BW004_GD-4-16   99
2022-06-30 14:15:40    BW004_GD-4-17   50
2022-06-30 14:16:00    BW004_GD-4-18   100
.
.
.
```

```
SELECT LEFT([DateAndTime], 10) ,
    [TagName]
    , MAX([DataValue]) AS MaxValue
FROM [RTDB].[dbo].[Env_AI]
GROUP BY LEFT([DateAndTime], 10), [TagName]
ORDER BY [TagName]
```

This SQL works but does not include time.

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: I added your requested answer bellow @KIHA

Comment: @Squirrel SELECT LEFT ([DateAndTime], 10) ,
      [TagName]
      ,MAX([DataValue]) AS MaxValue
  FROM [RTDB].[dbo].[Env_AI]
 GROUP BY  LEFT ([DateAndTime], 10), [TagName] ORDER BY  [TagName]

Comment: but this SQL doesn't contain time.

Comment: @KIHA can you provide some more rows of the tables

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of your recently [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73272341/how-to-group-by-day-from-charfield-using-sql) - please do not do that. Improve your original question.

Comment: [Edit] your attempt into your question. And explain this result `2022-06-30 18:20:30    BW004_GD-4-16   99` comes from? "18:20:30" doesn't exist in your initial data. Nor do many of your other desired results. Also if you want to make it easy for people to assist, try providing the DDL+DML.

Comment: @DaleK Okay. "18:20:30" is my misstake. first low 2022-06-30 18:20:30  BW004_GD-4-16   99. i  will try providing the DDL+DML

Comment: The first thing you need to do is make sure your desired results match your provided sample data.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I'll add details to the question and edit sample data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use [dense_rank()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to find the rows with maximum `DataValue` (partition) by `Date` and `TagName`

```
select *
from (
    select *,
        rn = dense_rank() over (
            partition by left(DateAndTime, 10), 
            TagName 
            order by DataValue desc
        )
    from RTDB.dbo.Env_AI
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This code works. But my data is over 4 million and it takes time. Can I get only the earliest date each tag among the max?

Comment: @KIHA that sounds like a separate question. Either way, provide sample data and desired results. Although 4m rows isn't many, so maybe you need some indexes in your database.

Comment: I am currently developing a backend using django rest framework. I used django orm, but it is too slow to use. Now your query works fine, but it takes more than 3 seconds. So I changed to display only the earliest time among the maximum values.

Comment: Unfortunately my main language is Python and I'm not familiar with sql yet. I need your help.

Comment: @KIHA to make this run fast, you need to create a computed column `left(DateAndTime, 10)` and then create an index `(YourNewColumn, TagName, DataValue) INCLUDE (OtherColumnsHere)`. I'd also advise to use `CAST(DateAndTime AS date)` rather than `left(DateAndTime, 10)`